# How to setup a 301 redirect using mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I must admit, mod_rewrites are still a bit of black magic for me and I try to stay well away from them unless I really, really need to us them, now I do!

I've just migrated my site to become a multi lingual site and in doing so I've made the following change to the structure.

oldwebsite.net/somefile.php >> newwebsite.com/xx/somefile.php
oldwebsite.net/somefolder/somefile.php >> newwebsite.com/xx/somefolder/somefile.php

Now, I know how to do individual 301 redirects, but I got tons of pages and the new structure hasn't changed the page name so I would like to avoid setting up hundreds of individual 301 redirects, help!!

Thanks,
Mikael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in your `oldwebsite` htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldwebsite\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newwebsite.com/xx/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey I probably should have mentioned that I haven't actually changed the location of the site as such, just changing the URL so this doesn't quite work as the rewrite then affect everything under the new domain too. I guess what it's missing is, "if the url you're requesting = old website, then rewrite as follows".

Comment: Oh right. You can see my edited answer. Also, you'll maybe have to clear your browser's cache before trying again (old rule is now in cache)

Comment: That worked perfectly for the homepage but it doesn't work if I try to browse a specific page, say oldwebsite.net/oldpage/ not sure if it's some of the wordpress rewrites interfering...thanks again for your help!

Comment: Just answered my on question, it was wordpress, added your rules on top and it works like a charm!!! Thank you!